# Do option types collapse?

Tags: f#, option-type

Here is an option type in F#:

```
type Option<'a> =
   | Some of 'a
   | None
```

Suppose I have an `Option` of an `Option`:

```
type Option2<'a> =
   | O of Option<'a>
   | None
```

Does it get collapsed down to just one `Option`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. That would be a really strange behaviour. Also, your second definition won't compile, because the first case lacks a name.

Comment: What happens if you try?

Comment: FWIW, you can easily 'flatten' normal `option` values with a *bind*: `Some (Some 42) |> Option.bind id` becomes `Some 42`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, F# has a **nominal type system**. *Structurally* equivalent types are not compatible. So even if you had `Option` and `Option2` exactly the same (except the name), these types would be different. Your case is different, similar to asking whether a list of ints and a list of lists of ints are the same.

```
let hasOptionType (_ : Option<_>) = ()
let hasOption2Type (_ : Option2<_>) = ()

let o = Option.None
let o2 = Option2.None

hasOptionType o
//hasOption2Type o // does not compile
//hasOptionType o2 // does not compile
hasOption2Type o2
```

You can have type aliases though that work both ways:

```
type IntOption = Option<int>

let isOptionOfInt (_ : Option<int>) = ()
let isIntOption (_ : IntOption) = ()

let i = IntOption.None
let i2 = Option<int>.None

isOptionOfInt i
isOptionOfInt i2
isIntOption i
isIntOption i2
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a little confusing because you talk about an `Option` of an `Option`, but then show a type which is your own `Option2` type containing an `Option`.

I'm going to assume your question is really this: Does `Some (Some x)` collapse down to `Some x`?

The answer to that is no. That collapsing would implicitly change the type and you would lose some of the type safety that `Option` provides. And the distinction between the collapsed and non-collapsed versions may be important. Take this example.

```
match List.tryHead [Some 1; None; Some 2] with
| Some (Some x) -> sprintf "The first item exists with a value of %i" x
| Some None     -> "The first item exists but it has no value"
| None          -> "The list was empty"
```

The `List.tryHead` function returns the first element of the list, or None if the list is empty. We are passing it a list of `Option<int>` so it returns an `Option<Option<int>>`

We are able to match on the return values to cover all the different possible cases of that return type. This may be useful if you want to handle those cases differently.

But we still have the ability to treat `Some None` and `None` as equivalent:

```
match List.tryHead [Some 1; None; Some 2] with
| Some (Some x) -> sprintf "The first item exists with a value of %i" x
| _             -> "No value found"
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the option types you have defined will not be automatically merged into some other type. They are separate discriminated unions and must be handled as such.

Take the following example, which shows how you must pattern match and construct values of `Option2`:

```fsharp
let info x = match x with
            | O (Some i) -> sprintf "Found %d" i
            | O (Option.None) -> "The wrapping Option2 contained None"
            | Option2.None -> "The wrapper was None"

System.Console.WriteLine(info (O (Some 3)))
System.Console.WriteLine(info (O Option.None))
System.Console.WriteLine(info Option2.None)

// prints:
// Found 3
// The wrapping Option2 contained None
// The wrapper was None
```